# i have a problem in git&github i'm trying to fix ssh password but nothing happen

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, github

I wanted to push my file from git-command to GitHub, but when I do that they send me this message:

```
("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /c/Users/acer/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /c/Users/acer/.ssh/known_hosts:1
RSA host key for github.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository."")
```

I tried to change ssh-password but nothing happened.
I expected that if I changed ssh-password, it would work, but the truth is it didn't work.

Can you tell me how can fix it ?

Comment: You need to change the fingerprint in `/c/Users/acer/.ssh/known_hosts` as is shown by the error message. The one that is sent by the remote system is the correct one from Github as you can see from the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints). See [known_hosts file](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/ssh-known_hosts-file). There is also guidance on the bottom of the page on how to resolve this error.